# Chrome FATAL crash

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome, meteor, v8

I have a Node.js / Meteor app that is left consistently running on a screen - it works no problem for around 20 hours, then without fail (when I'm out of the office) I get the infamous "Aw Snap" screen:

[image]

I have checked the chrome_debug log and the following line indicates the crash:

> [3868:3656:0515/030350:FATAL:platform_canvas.cc(70)] SK_CRASH

However gives me nothing to go on - googling the error and variations retrieves very little results. What could I do to debug further?

Comment: What version of meteor are you using? Have a go at using the "Timeline" section in the chrome debug tools to have a look at whats happening to memory,events & frames and what might cause it

Comment: @Akshat the version is 0.5.9 and it's the unofficial windows build. I'll leave that running - however when the "broken" page comes up, it does so on the console as well - meaning the results will be untraceable

Comment: I'm not 100% sure on how to use it but I do see a record button there, it might be dumped somewhere to disk

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most probably, you are running out of memory, and Skia (the Chrome graphics engine) is unable to create another canvas, hence the crash.

You should use the Profiles panel of the DevTools: take two heap snapshots and compare them, or use the [Uncovering DOM leaks](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/heap-profiling#views_dom) technique.

You can get some insight of what's happening in the native land by using *Native memory profiling* ([explained](https://plus.google.com/+AddyOsmani/posts/FVrf76d7G5U))

Comment: Cheers - it appears to be the case. I've used the Heap profile to check, it goes up to around 150mb and then crashe - using a comparison I can see that a lot of the HTML that Meteor replaces doesn't get removed